# Dealing with '/'es in links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, hyperlink

I am reading in a number of strings which have `/`'es through them, the most common example being dates/numbers like 05/06, 07/08, etc.

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 and generating links off of these strings read out of DB, which therein lies the problem.

Obviously a link to:

`www.mysite.com/yearperiod/05/06/detail`

will not work the same as a link to

`www.mysite.com/yearperiod/2005/detail`

What is a good solution to this problem? My first thought is to convert every `/` to a `-` but then I run into the problem/overhead of having to keep track of which ones were converted, so that when writing back to the DB I don't inadvertantly switch a valid `-` to a `/` (if that makes sense)

**edit:** come to think of it, I wouldn't know how to keep track of each converted `/` ... hmmmm.....

**edit1:** Given this string: "2001/2 - Fruit"

```
var encodedLinkText = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(linkText); //result is "2001%2f2+-+Fruit"
```

but then if I call that linkhelper from my view the rendered link comes out as :
view source:
`<li><a href="2001%2f2+-+Fruit">2001/2 - Fruit</a></li>`
rendered link:
`http://localhost:XXXX/Period/2001/2+-+Fruit`

while I need it as:

`http://localhost:XXXX/Period/2001%2f2+-+Fruit`

**edit2:** The browser (testing in chrome) is automatically converting the `%2f` to a `/` . What now?

**edit3:** uh oh... looks like IE behaves properly (as required)... hmmm...

- **IE** displays the link properly (encoded) and after clicking it remains encoded.
- **Firefox** displays the link decoded and after clicking is encoded.
- **Chrome** displays link decoded and after clicking is decoded.

Comment: interesting hint the way so deals with it, simply removing the slash from the link completely `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648634/dealing-with-es-in-links`

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem. If you are using firefox, what you will see in the source code is the converted one and what you see in the status bar when you hover it is with the slash, but when you click it, it will give you the encoded string.

Comment: if any chance, could you post your extension method here?

Comment: can if you want but all it is doing is the `Server.UrlEncode()` unfortunately when I click on the the link (which has converted the `%2f` back to `/`) it does not give me the encoded string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entity in your database is outputting the string '05/06' that entity must also have some sort of unique identifier, such as a primary key integer. Couldn't you include that as part of the URL so your above example becomes:

```
www.mysite.com/yearperiod/123/05-06/detail
```

Then you can convert your slashes to dashes to your hearts content without worrying about converting them back, because the actual database look-up is performed in the ID number (the '123' part) and not the date string.

If you look at StackOverflow's URLs they do something similar:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/3648634/dealing-with-es-in-links
```

3648634 is the database ID for this question which is used to perform the look-up, the '*dealing-with-es-in-links*' part is merely there for user friendly descriptive URLs and Search Engine Optimisation.

Here's a ToFriendlyUrl() method that can generate these nice looking, SO style, URLs without having to resort to URL Encoding which can make URLs look ugly:

```
public static class UrlEncoder 
{ 
    public static string ToFriendlyUrl (this UrlHelper helper, 
        string urlToEncode) 
    { 
        urlToEncode = (urlToEncode ?? "").Trim().ToLower(); 

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(); 

        foreach (char ch in urlToEncode) 
        { 
            switch (ch) 
            { 
                case ' ': 
                    url.Append('-'); 
                    break; 
                case '&': 
                    url.Append("and"); 
                    break; 
                case '\'': 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || 
                        (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) 
                    { 
                        url.Append(ch); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        url.Append('-'); 
                    } 
                    break; 
            } 
        } 

        return url.ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

You can tweak the code to deal with other special characters such as &ampersands& , but you should get the general idea. You can use in your view like so:

```
<%= Url.ToFriendlyUrl(item.Title) %>
```

**So in a nutshell, don't relly on UrlEncoding, but use a FriendlyUrl utility like the one above and include the database ID for the actual database look-up.**

I've written a blog post in this subject her http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls

Comment: Wow, this is a much better solution...Can't believe I didn't think about using that instead, seems so obvious now! The converting back was what I was worried about, but relying on the id will be better and then I can do whatever I want to the url without worrying about 'uniqueness'. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Server.UrlEncode`.  You can UrlEncode all of your string.

```
string strDatePeriod = Server.UrlEncode("05/06");
```

To convert it back to its original string, you'll just have to use the `Server.UrlDecode`

```
string origStr = Server.UrlDecode(strDatePeriod);
```

Comment: Can I only use that code in the view? I'm trying to use it in my Pagelink helper class. Which namespace should be imported for `Server.` I thought it was `System.Web`

Comment: you can just call it directly via `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode` and `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode` from the namespace `System.Web`

Comment: Please  see my edits, the `/` is the problem, the `Server.UrlEncode` seems to be working but when it is rendered the slash is converted back ?